# Adding DNN site to Visual Studios

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-4.5, dotnetnuke

I'm building a new DNN site. I've got everything up and running with IIS and can navigate to the site with dnndev.me, but I'm wondering how I can import the project to VS2013? I know that I can make modules in VS, but I'd like to have a solution for the entire site. I've tried creating a new project and dragging the site over to the new project, but that introduced a chain of errors. I know it can be done somehow, I've seen it in projects I've worked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File -> Open Website`

Navigate to the website directory

In DNN, there are two different ways to develop modules.

1. Web Application project (WAP)
2. Web Site project (WSP)

Here is a good article on it by Mitchel Sellers: [WAP vs WSP](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/01/02/wap-or-wsp-which-to-use-and-why.aspx)